# Devemos usar "há" ou "havia" na frase abaixo?

Tags: tempo-verbal, semântica

"Eu não usava um casaco de peles há/havia cinco anos."

Qual a forma gramaticalmente correta?  Podemos usar as duas?   Porque?

Comment: Para meu ouvido apenas "havia" funciona com "usava" (ambos se aplicando até um momento no passado), o "há" teria que ser com "uso".

Comment: **fazia cinco anos**.  A frase inteira precisa estar no passado se você usar "usava". Então, havia. No presente, fica: Eu não **uso** casaco de peles **há**cinco anos. [presente]

Comment: @Fabricio G  Porque apagou sua resposta?  Ela faz sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Eu vejo duas possibilidades em pt-BR:

1 - "Em 2014 eu **usei** um casaco de peles. Eu não usava um casaco de peles **havia** cinco anos." (ou seja, em 2009)
2 - "Estou usando um casaco de peles, ou pretendo usar, ou apenas quero mencionar que não tenho usado. Eu não **uso** um casaco de peles **há** cinco anos."

Comment: Aguardo uma resposta mais completa.